# how to get objects of the last X hours?

Tags: django

I'm making an app where you can upload images, but I want to let users to post one image per hour so how can I filter Images before one hour?

here's the code:

```
if Images.objects.filter(username=request.user).filter(pub_date=LAST HOUR).exists():
    messages.info(request, 'you are allowed to post one image per hour.')
    return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

qs = Images.objects.filter(username=request.user,
                      pub_date__gte=timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=1))
```

**References:**

- [`gte` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#gte)
- [Django `timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now)
- [Python's `timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)